# Is there any way for Mac terminal to run npm start and flask run simultaneously?

Tags: python, shell, flask, nodes

Im trying to run `npm start` and `flask run` at the same time in terminal on Mac, I tried to do it with shell script -> .sh like this

```
./chinmap_flask.sh

cd INS/FYP/chinmap

export PORT=3001

npm start
```

==================================

chinmap_flask.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
cd ~
cd Desktop
cd INS/FYP/chinmap/src/Backend/frontendData
export FLASK_APP=../app
export FLASK_ENV=development
flask run
```

==================================

And this is not working too:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start && cd ~ && cd Desktop && ./chinmap_flask.sh"
},
```

npm server started successfully, however, the terminal stop running other scripts after `npm start`, are there any possible ways to run both of them in one shell script or single line of terminal command? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to run two commands at the same time. You can try this but I'm not sure if it will work:

```
npm start && flask run
```

You could try adding a new tab in the terminal with <kbd>Cmd + T</kbd> And in the first tab run `flask run` and run `npm start` in the second tab. This won't run both the commands in a single terminal command but the node server and the flask server will be running.

If you have trouble doing this check out this post: https://superuser.com/questions/286157/how-can-i-open-a-new-tab-in-terminal-in-mac

Answer (score 0):

Just add `&` at the end of any command to run it in the background and get your Terminal back for doing other stuff:

```
# Start flask in background
./chinmap_flask.sh &

# Set up and start npm in background
cd INS/FYP/chinmap
export PORT=3001
npm start &
```